# Update function not working in AR application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox, augmented-reality

I am working on AR application that shows the nearby POI's. As you can see below screenshot ArAlignedMap has a script that allow us to create a POI using real world coordinates.
[WorldScaleAr][1]

One of the POI's Marker Prefab that i assigned is POI45. POI45 has objects in below screenshot.
[POI45][2]

I wrote a script for LabelIcon. This script is below;

Once the script run, the color of POI is changes but not changes in every frame. Why it doesn't update the color of POI?

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using static System.Math;
using Mapbox.Examples; // example script import

public class gradient45 : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 temp;
    float temp2;
    float distances;
    int z = 2;
    float gra = 0;
    double r = 6371000;
    double[,] coords = new double[,] { { 39.872446, 32.735564 } }; // Eğitim Fakültesi
    double lat1;
    double lat2;
    double lon1;
    double lon2;
    double user_lat;
    double user_lat_rad;
    double user_lon;
    double user_lon_rad;
    String x;
    String y;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // get poi Location
        lat1 = Math.PI * coords[0, 0] / 180.0;
        // lat2 = Math.PI * user[0, 0] / 180.0;
        lon1 = Math.PI * coords[0, 1] / 180.0;
        // lon2 = Math.PI * user[0, 1] / 180.0;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Get user location
        // Latitude
        x = getLocation.x1.ToString();
        user_lat = Convert.ToDouble(x);
        user_lat_rad = Math.PI * user_lat / 180.0; // Radian
        // Longitude
        y = getLocation.y1.ToString();
        user_lon = Convert.ToDouble(y);
        user_lon_rad = Math.PI * user_lon / 180.0; // Radian

        // Change POIs sizes
        distances = Convert.ToSingle(distance(user_lat_rad, user_lon_rad));
        temp2 = gra;
        temp2 = temp2 + 100f;
        gra = temp2;

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color((gra/255f), 161f/255f, 127f/255f);


    }
    public double distance(double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        // Haversine Formula
        // Lat2,Lon2 = User Location
        // Lat1,Lon1 = POI Location
        double dist1 = Sqrt((Pow(Sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2), 2)) + Cos(lat2) * Cos(lat2) * (Pow(Sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2), 2)));
        double distance = 2 * r * Asin(dist1);
        return distance;
    }
} ```


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONcxC.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh9q2.jpg
````

Comment: Hi! A side question, what is the purpose of your class-global property temp2? It only seems to be used in one function, and in that function, it looks like its use could be replaced by writing `gra += 100f;`. (Generally speaking, for better future maintenance try make your variable names precisely describe their role, and try to define them in the smallest scope possible.) Also note that you currently call `GetComponent<Renderer>()` on every Update; a common thing in Unity is to reference it once during start, then re-use that reference.

Comment: For your issue, how did you determine that the color does not change in every Update? Do you use a Debug.Log, if so what is its code, and what its output?

Comment: I see them on the screen, the color's does'nt change. When I call the script it doesn't have an error message.

Comment: Does the value of gra change? (E.g. add `Debug.Log(gra);` before the `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color` line.)

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10tWqV6R6tm9Djs26HXbknxKba5NbIGIo)

Comment: yes it does change

Comment: What Shader are you using on the object you're changing the color on? And what are some of the typical min/ max values for gra you're seeing in the debug log?